# Find the half life using exponential expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

> a) For a particular radioactive substance, the mass $m$ (in grams) at a
>   time $t$ in years is given by $m = m_0e^{-0.02t}$, where $m_0$ is the
>   original mass.  If the original mass is $500$g, find the
>   mass after $10$ years.
>
> b)  The half life of any material is the time taken for half of the
>   mass to decay.  Find the half-life of this substance.

a) $500e^{-0.02}$ - 490.1

b) $e^{-0.02t} = 0.5$

$\Rightarrow\:$ $-0.02t = \ln(0.5)$

$\Rightarrow\:$ $t = \frac{\ln(0.5)}{-0.02}$

$\Rightarrow\:$ $t = 34.7$

Are my workings correct?

Comment: $(b)$ seems to be ok, but part (a) is not ok. Review and correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the formula

$m = m_0e^{-0.02t}$

and are given the original mass, $m_0$, of $500$g and want to find the mass, $m$, after $t=10$ years.

All you have to do is plug in these values

$m = m_0e^{-0.02t} = 500e^{-0.02 \cdot 10}$

---

Part $b$ is correct.